# int versus unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Suppose we have a loop that runs for 100 times. Does using `unsigned char` instead of `int` for its counter make a difference? And also using `i += 1U` instead of `i++`? Or do compilers take care of that?

Comment: @Shaihi What do you mean by wraparounds?

Comment: If you increment a signed char past 128, it goes negative.  That's wrapping around.  Some compilers will make slower code if the loop index isn't an `int`, but some won't, and even then, it rarely matters.

Comment: @David If you have to ask what are *wraparound* and *bottleneck*, you'd better stay away from such details for now, also known as premature [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization), and concentrate on writing working code.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/question-about-unsigned-and-signed-comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In simple case `int` vs `unsigned char` gives the same code for me:

```
    for ( unsigned char i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
01081001  mov         esi,64h  
01081006  jmp         main+10h (1081010h)  
01081008  lea         esp,[esp]  
0108100F  nop  
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
01081010  mov         eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::endl (108204Ch)]  
01081015  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (1082050h)]  
0108101B  push        eax  
0108101C  push        1  
0108101E  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (1082044h)]  
01081024  mov         ecx,eax  
01081026  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (1082048h)]  
0108102C  dec         esi  
0108102D  jne         main+10h (1081010h)  
    }
    return 0;
```

You should profile your code and then optimize slow parts. **Do not start with [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).**

Comment: Nothing *too* exotic, then. :-)

Comment: In this case, the compiler has spotted that `i` isn't used within the loop, and that the loop bound is small enough not to cause overflow, and replaced it with a counter running down to zero. There almost certainly will be a difference if you output `i` rather than `1`, and if the loop bound isn't known at compile time.

Comment: Compilers can sometimes optimize better with `int` loop counters than any unsigned type, [because signed overflow is undefined behaviour](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  Also, specifically for x86, `int` temporaries don't have a risk of partial-register slowdowns.  More generally, if the compiler can't prove that a `uint8_t` won't wrap, but you also use the loop counter in an expression (e.g. as an array index, or where integer promotion rules promote it to `int`), it has to make code that actually uses 8bit and then zero-extends to 32 or 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

Using `i += 1U` will make no difference. The compiler will treat it identically to `i++`. The case of `int` versus `unsigned char` is more complex.

The *best* answer is simply not to worry about it in the first place unless a) your code absolutely must run faster and b) you have identified the loop as a major bottleneck. Remember Knuth's Law: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

The next-best answer is that the compiler will probably optimize away any difference. Even if it wouldn't, 100 repetitions is peanuts. The loop index operations are totally insignificant.

But in the interests of "full disclosure", as it were, the answer to your int/uchar question is that there is almost certainly no performance difference. Almost. Many of the relevant factors are left unspecified by the C standards, so it is theoretically possible that a C environment could exist where a uchar would be faster.

A char is defined by the standard to be the smallest addressable unit of memory. That's probably (virtually always) going to be one byte of eight bits. An int will be at least as large as a char (or the char obviously couldn't be the smallest addressable unit of memory, and it must be able to hold any value from -32,767 to +32,767. (It is *not* required to hold -32,768, though virtually all do.) This means that the int must be at least 16 bits. In practice, an int is often a machine word. This has the advantage of being fast. On your machine and mine, it's almost certainly 32 or 64 bits.

Now, suppose we're on a machine with 8-bit words. Suppose that there is no special hardware support for 16-bit integers. (This may or may not correspond to any actual machine.) The char will be 8 bits and the int likely 16. Operations on ints are likely expensive, so a char might be faster.

Suppose we have 32-bit words and 32-bit ints. Suppose your code contains four (8-bit) char variables. Suppose further that your compiler packs local variables in as much as is physically possible, speed be damned. If one of those chars is your loop counter, it may be packed in a word with other variables. Every operation on that char may be costly, as it must be re-packed. (This assumes a rather dumb compiler.) An int counter, however, could not be packed with any other variable. In this case, the int might run slightly faster.

Remember, both of these examples are contrived. I don't know of any real systems that work those ways, but a system *could*. (Note: If I have presented a case incompatible with the specifications, please tell me so that I can correct it.)

So, in the real world, how does one decide what type to use? From the [C Language FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html):

> If you might need large values (above 32,767 or below -32,767), use long. Otherwise, if space is very important (i.e. if there are large arrays or many structures), use short. Otherwise, use int. If well-defined overflow characteristics are important and negative values are not, or if you want to steer clear of sign-extension problems when manipulating bits or bytes, use one of the corresponding unsigned types. (Beware when mixing signed and unsigned values in expressions, though; see question 3.19.)
>
> Although character types (especially unsigned char) can be used as ``tiny'' integers, doing so is sometimes more trouble than it's worth. The compiler will have to emit extra code to convert between char and int (making the executable larger), and unexpected sign extension can be troublesome. (Using unsigned char can help; see question 12.1 for a related problem.)

The rest of that page, and indeed the FAQ as a whole, is well worth the read.

In this case? Use an int and don't worry about it.

Comment: Processors where 8-bit operations are faster than 16-bit operations do exist.  Indeed, there are probably more such processors in the world than processors where 16-bit operations are as fast as 8-bit.  A 16-bit processor would be overkill for a typical household thermostat, alarm clock, light timer, remote control, exercise machine, or other such device (some such devices use hard-wired electronics, but a lot of them use 8-bit microcontrollers).  Even a typical computer will include some 8-bit microcontrollers inside it (e.g. to scan the keyboard).

Comment: If anything, `int` will be faster for local temporaries on x86 CPUs.  Making the counter wrap to 8 bits is extra work for the compiler, and can introduce partial-register slowdowns or false dependencies due to x86-specific stuff.  Also keep in mind that compilers can assume that signed integers don't wrap (because that's undefined behaviour), but `unsigned` is required to have the expected semantics even when it wraps.  This can allow better loop optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

This will usually not make any difference . Try and measure if you really care but first be sure that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: That's how a thing that slowers the program the most is called. For example if your program spends 99% reading files you don't care that much about what it does the remaining 1% of time since reading files is a bottleneck.

Comment: You're right that we shouldn't get hung up on this.  Having said that, it's also reasonable to make a general effort to be efficient.  In other words, I'm not suggesting premature optimization, just saying we shouldn't throw cycles out the window as a matter of habit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, leave these sorts of micro-optimisations up to the compiler. Even if there *is* a difference, it will only become obvious if you're doing it a bazillion times a second. For the vast majority of cases, it won't matter one bit as most programs spend 99.9% of their time waiting around for something to happen.

You're also more likely to get a better return on your investment if you concentrate on the macro stuff like algorithm selection.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using ++i and not i+=1 or i++

Comment: That is horrible advice. It won't make one bit of difference with an `int`, unless the compiler writers are brain-dead.

Comment: @paxdiablo You're not only talking to the compiler (are you really?), you're also writing for those who will read your code...

Comment: @Roi Do you expect ++i or i++ to make a difference in terms of performance?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes, it won't make a lick of different *here*.  Emphasis intended.  In general, it's a good habit to pre-increment because it can and does make some difference for more complex STL containers.

Comment: @pascal: I can't speak for Roi, but I expect it to be a good habit that will pay in other cases.

Comment: yes it was a suggestion as a habit. sorry I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: pascal, if there's someone reading code that knows `++i` but not `i++`, I think they should stop reading right now. And, for Steven, I would think that once you're reached the point where you're writing `op++` things for your classes, you would know, or soon learn, the fact that pre-inc can be more optimal. But the OP specifically asked for ints and this answer, apart from not even explaining _why_ it can be a good idea for complex classes, is irrelevant. I didn't downvote since I thought of give Roi a chance to change the advice or at least explain why it may be good in other circumstances.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Given that pre-increment is sometimes better and never worse, I would think there'd be no reason to use both.  I'd rather just stick to the one that's never wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know performance figures change from compiler to compiler. In addition to that performance might vary from OS to OS as well.

Better approach is write a small program to measure the performance of operations you are interested.

[Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880)  covers a lot of details about performance of primitive operations.Also it shows how to write some programs to measure performance of those operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about micro optimization like this one, you have to know your compiler by heart. Try both way and compare the assembly generated.
A good rule of thumb is to choose the variable type according to its semantics (`char` is for ASCII characters, `int` for integers, and so on ...) rather than to its size (except to align your structures).

Two little things though :

- On a 32bits architecture, the size of a processor registry is 32bits, so using accessing a `char` (8 bits) takes two operations while accessing an `int` is only one.
- If you do not intend to use the value before incrementation, prefer pre-incrementation to post-incrementation. This is especially important in C++ where post-incrementation can result in some unwanted constructor calls.

Comment: Whatever compiler Kirill used was able to optimize this by promoting the index up from 8-bit to 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

As the difference is going to be (at most) a fraction of a clock-cycle per increment, you will literally need to run the entire loop 1,000,000 before you start to approach the threshold of human perception; and that assumes running the loop 1,000,000 times and then instantaneously alerting the user it has finished.

Assuming the loop does *anything* else; or, that single notification is *any* form of IO (which by definition it is), you have to run the (1 million iteration) outer-loop another 1000 thousand times! before your user is going to notice.

Seriously! You are worrying about the wrong things.

Answer (score 0):

Most compiler will recognize that you are using the variable for a loop and so will keep it in a register.

On i386 CPUs it may use an 8-bit register, because they are accessible directly with no performance penalty (16 Bit Values can only be accessed with a "16 bit override opcode" leading to one more byte in the code segment).

However, an 8bit register is as fast as a 32bit one, so the only benefit from using a 8 bit one is that there is one more left for another 8 bit variable (only one, because the higher 16bit cannot be accessed directly).

To summarizes: Let the compiler optimize - it will do it if possible, but in this case it will also make almost no difference.

Other CPUs (PowerPC, ARM etc.) have other behaviour.