# Why is an unsigned int 1 lower than a char y -1?

Tags: c

```
main() {
    unsigned x = 1;
    char y = -1;

    if (x > y)
        printf("x>y");
    else
        printf("x<=y");
}
```

I expected `x>y`,
but I had to change `unsigned int` to `signed int` to get the expected result.

Comment: char y=-1; it should throw an error i think it should be char y='-1' instead

Comment: @Devjosh, no you are wrong. '-1' is not a valid character.

Comment: @Devjosh: `'-1'` throws a warning because it's actually `'-'` and `'1'` combined, not the number "-1". The latter is ignored.

Comment: @Devjosh No, actually i'm putting value (not ASCII) in signed char datatype (-128 to 127).

Comment: ok thanks  @taskinoor and Lekensteyn got it :)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: char constants have integer type, and the value of a char constant with more than one character is implementation-defined. (ISO C99 §6.4.4.4 ¶10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsigned and signed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/unsigned-and-signed-comparison)

Comment: [How implicit conversion work with signed character and unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47528611/995714)

Comment: @phuclv closed the other way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `char` is equivalent to `signed char`:

- `char` is promoted to `int` (Integer Promotions, ISO C99 §6.3.1.1 ¶2)
- Since `int` and `unsigned int` have the same rank, `int` is converted to `unsigned int` (Arithmetic  Conversions, ISO C99 §6.3.1.8)

If `char` is equivalent to `unsigned char`:

- `char` may be promoted to either `int` or `unsigned int`:

  - If `int` can represent all `unsigned char` values (typically because `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`), `char` is converted to `int`.
  - Otherwise (typically because `sizeof(char)==sizeof(int)`), `char` is converted to `unsigned`.
- Now we have one operand that is either `int` or `unsigned int`, and another that is `unsigned int`. The first operand is converted to `unsigned int`.

Integer promotions:
 An expression of a type of lower rank that `int` is converted to `int` if `int` can hold all of the values of the original type, to `unsigned int` otherwise.

Arithmetic conversions:
Try to convert to the larger type. When there is conflict between signed and unsigned, if the larger (including the case where the two types have the same rank) type is unsigned, go with unsigned. Otherwise, go with signed only in the case it can represent all the values of both types.

Conversions to integer types(ISO C99 §6.3.1.3):

Conversion of an out-of-range value to an unsigned integer type is done via wrap-around (modular arithmetic).

Conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type is implementation defined, and can raise a signal (such as SIGFPE).

Comment: Edited: mental lapse due to lack of sleep.

Comment: +1 detailed and correct answer. (And because I almost always +1 decent correct answers when the accepted answer is wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

When using signed and unsigned in single operation the signed got promoted to unsigned by C's automatic type conversion. If the bit patter of `-1` is considered an unsigned number then it is a very very high value. So `x > y` is false.

Comment: @taskinoor: It doesn't matter what the bit pattern of -1 is "considered as an unsigned number", it's the _value_ that matters when it is converted to an unsigned type.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, that's what I meant. May be my language is not good enough.

Comment: @taskinoor: When you talk about the bit pattern of -1, it seemed to me that you were implying that the implicit promotion from `char` to `unsigned` depends on the underlying representation of a `char` in the implementation (e.g. two's complement) which is not correct.

Comment: -1 bit pattern is irrelevant. Conversion to unsigned is an arithmetic operation not a bit-pattern-reinterpretation.