# How to compare Signed Char to a literal constant?

Tags: c, type-conversion

The API provides a function `signed char getDirection();`, that returns 1 for "forward", 0 for "motionless", -1 for "backward."

And of course, as explained in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048840/why-is-comparing-a-signed-char-and-unsigned-int-not-working-right) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087992/unsigned-int-and-signed-char-comparison), a simple comparison:

```
    if(getDirection() == -1) { ... }
```

fails. Okay, I understand why it fails. But I just can't find how to make it work! I tried casting the left side to `(int)`, the right side to `(signed char)`, still nada...

edit:

```
 signed char a = getDirection();
 printf("%d\n",(int) a);
 printf("%d\n",(int) getDirection());
```

Results:

```
 -1
 255
```

edit2: per request:

```
const signed char getDirection(uchar d)
{
    if(d >= config.directional_inputs.channelCount) return -2;

    return shm->input_state.directional_inputs[d].direction;
}
```

Comment: @AlexD: I wish. Well, actually the test statement is in format `printf("val: %d, comparison: %d", getDirection(), (getDirection() == DIRECTION_BACK) );` where the constant is `#define DIRECTION_BACK -1`

Comment: Your code is correct. Check if `getDirection()` actually returns -1. Show the output of your `printf`. Also show your actual code, maybe there is just a stray ';' somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Output: "val: -1, comparison: 0". A colleague suspects a compiler error.

Comment: Try this: `printf("DIRECTION_BACK: %d, val: %d, comparison: %d", DIRECTION_BACK, getDirection(), (getDirection() == DIRECTION_BACK) );` just to be sure your macros are defined correctly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The values are okay. DIRECTION_BACK is -1. Moreover, as you see in the edit, if I compare `a` to DIRECTION_BACK it returns true.

Comment: @SF what compiler are you using ? Quite strange indeed.

Comment: @Michale Waltz: The API (getDirection() and family) is compiled through MinGW GCC. The code that links against that API (the problem statements) is compiled with TCC (Tiny C Compiler).

Comment: Hmm, didn't you forget to include a .h  or to explicitely declare `const signed char getDirection(uchar d);` in your compilation unit ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Don't you think that would fail to compile? (but not to sound snide - the header is included, the linking works fine, the function reacts to physical inputs correctly and returns the correct value (once we manage to squeeze a signed value out of it. Otherwise it returns 0,1,255); the same header file is used for compiling the api and for linking it against the problem code.)

Comment: Some compilers assume *any parameters returning int* for an undeclared function for compatibility with 1970s K&R C. But I you have checked anything, I would suspect a non conformant compiler (I do not know TCC, except for the ooold Turbo C Compiler )

Comment: If the function really is declared as `signed char getDirection();` you shouldn't get -1 and 255 in your example, are you sure there't nothing else going on ? (i.e. can you create a complete compilable example that shows that behavior , and what platform/compiler are you using) ?

Comment: You're printing `getDirection()` but the function definition is `getDirection(uchar d)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `getDirection()` really returns a signed char, it should work, since a signed char of `0xff` should correctly be promoted to a -1 integer.

If unsure, you could try to write

```
int dir = getDirection();
// optionnally for extensive tests : fprintf(stderr, "getDirection : %d\n", dir);
if ((dir == -1) || (dir == 255)) { ... }
```

The 255 would catch any conversion problem, for example `getDirection()` returning a signed char ... what your last edit suggests ...

Comment: @MichaelWalz : It is. But I once had to use something like that for a library that returned a `char` and I had to use it on 2 platforms where char was signed on one and unsigned on the other. I've already seen (badly written) code where doc said `signed char` and code contained only `char` because a programmer thought that what he had on his system (char = signed char) was the standard, whereas standard says it is implementation dependant.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: My personal take is that 'char' alone always means an ASCII letter. If it's to be a number, it must be denoted as 'signed' or 'unsigned'.

Comment: @sf a `char` is not an ASCII letter, it is an 8 bit value. `char` alone is `unsigned char` or (most of the time) `signed char` depending on your compiler.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That depends on context. Is the literal `'A'` signed or unsigned? I denote the content of a variable by choosing the type prefix - if it's plain `char`, the correct format to printf() it to make sense is not %hhd or %hhu but %c.

Comment: @SF. : For recent or decent compilers, the standard is clear 6.2.5 §15 : *The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called
the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range,
representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char*

Comment: Assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`, a "signed char of `0xff`" does not exist. The range of `signed char` is from `-128` to `+127` (assuming 2's-complement). `0xff` is simply another way of writing `255`. A `signed char` whose *representation* is the same as that of an `unsigned char` with the value `0xff` does have the value `-1` (again, assuming CHAR_BIT==8 and 2's-complement).

Comment: @KeithThompson : I would say that the operation `signed char c = 0xFF;` is explicitely implementation defined, and could even raise a signal for `CHAR_BIT==8`: 6.3.1.3 §3 *[when] the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* - but common 2-complement implementations give `-1`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Yes, it's implementation-defined -- but one thing it *can't* do is store the value `0xFF` in `c` (again, given the assumptions stated above).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in `GetDirection` the part `return shm->input_state.directional_inputs[d].direction;` is performed. What is the type of that `direction` element? I am not sure about promotions here, but if it is `unsigned char`, it might just be copied into the return register `ax` and returned. That is, no sign extension is performed and ax is `0x000000ff`. The `ff` is assigned to `signed char a`, which is correct, and when `a` is used in the `printf` call, it gets properly sign extended. So the sign extension must be done in the return statement of `GetDirection` where it is apparently not done.

Try changing it to `return (signed char)shm->input_state.directional_inputs[d].direction;`

Comment: `direction` is `signed char` all the same, and it's the first in chain of assignments, getting a literal `-1` once input ports combine into 'backwards' configuration.

Comment: It still looks as if `GetDirection` does not do a sign extension. Check it with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange.

First, using different compilers might make a difference. They might have different rules how a signed char is supposed to be returned. Let's say the compiler for compiling the function assumes that signed char is returned as 8 bit in a 32 bit register, with the other bits zero or undefined - -1 is returned as 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111. The compiler for the call assumes that signed char is returned as 8 bit in a 32 bit register, sign extended, and therefore all 32 bits can be assumed to contain the correct value. So that compiler thinks the result is 255.

Second, I have seen problems where prototypes and functions didn't match. If there is a prototype for the function somewhere that says "char" instead of signed char, that would explain everything. Since the problem is strange, I'd ask the compiler for preprocessor output and check if anything strange is going on.

Comment: For recent or decent compilers, the standard is clear 6.3.1.1 §2-3 : *If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions* and *The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a ‘‘plain’’ char is treated as signed is implementation-defined* . But is TCC conformant ? and what version of standard ?