# Cannot enter in while statement

Tags: c, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsigned and signed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/unsigned-and-signed-comparison)
>   [unsigned int and signed char comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087992/unsigned-int-and-signed-char-comparison)

I have a strange behavior when i try to enter in this while statement:

```
unsigned u = 0;
int i = -2;

while(i < u)
{
    // Do something
    i++;
}
```

But it never enters, even if when i set a break point `i = -2` and `u = 0`. 
What am I doing wrong? How could i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the ANSI C standard defines that whenever there is a comparison between a qualified (your `unsigned int u`) and a non qualified type (your `int i`), the non qualified type gets promoted to a type of the same type (thus always `int`), but also inherits the qualifiers of the other quantity (i.e. it becomes `unsigned`).

When your `int`, whose value is equal to `-2`, becames `unsigned` the first byte undergoes this transformation: `0000 0010 -> 1111 1110`. Your `int` is now a very large positive number, certainly larger of your `unsigned int`.

There is a solution: cast to `signed`

```
while(i < (signed) u)
{
    // Do something
    i++;
}
```

By the way, probably your compiler should give you a warning.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the solution with a complete explanation.

Comment: Would it work if you defined i as ```signed int i```?

Comment: By default, if we do not specify either `signed` or `unsigned` most compiler settings will assume the type to be signed, so in this case `signed int i` has the same effect of `int i` and the result is the same.

Comment: @gliderkite: Are you sure? In C "qualified types" are e.g. `const int`, `volatile char`. `unsigned`/`signed` are not qualifiers (but type specifiers). Then there is: `unsigned a; signed int b; a < b;` where b is converted to `unsigned int`. **All** C compilers will assume a signed type because this is what the standard defines (except for `char`).

Comment: Your vocabulary and description are just wrong. "qualified" in the standard refers to `const` and `volatile`. What is going on here is something more subtle, namely implicit conversion. And the rules for that are not so direct as you suggest. I suggest that you delete your answer.

Comment: @undur_gongor You can read it yourself [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

Comment: @gliderkite: This is about C++. The question is about C. Maybe that page is even wrong/incorrect for C++ too.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a signed and unsigned integer and your problems started there...
Don't do that and it should work just fine.