# Print elements in an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confused about C macro expansion and integer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950051/confused-about-c-macro-expansion-and-integer-arithmetic)
>   [A riddle (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611724/a-riddle-in-c)

The output of the following C program is to print the elements in the array. But when actually run, it doesn't do so.

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
  int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

  int main()
  {
      int d;

      for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

      return 0;
  }
```

Why is that?

Comment: Is this homework? (If it is, you should tag it accordingly.)

Comment: Fantastically scary macro that includes the name of the array, instead of taking it as an argument. Very confusing.

Comment: See answer by Hari Mahadevan. Can you tell us what led you to setting variable d to -1 instead of zero?

Comment: [cannot-enter-in-while-statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849724/cannot-enter-in-while-statement/10849748#10849748) - [unsigned-and-signed-comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/unsigned-and-signed-comparison) - [unsigned-int-and-signed-char-comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087992/unsigned-int-and-signed-char-comparison)

Comment: I'm curious: is this code that you wrote, and don't understand, or is this code that professor provided as a what-does-this-obscure-code-do quiz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because `sizeof` is returning a value of type `size_t`, which is unsigned. This causes the comparison to promote the `-1` to unsigned, which is generally a very large value and thus make the comparison fail.

You should receive warnings for the sign mismatch.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof()` returns `unsigned int` and so in the <= comparison, `d` gets converted to `unsigned int`. -1 when converted to `unsigned int` is `0xffffff`. Since `0xffffff > (7-2)`, for-loop body won't be executed even once.

Comment: "*-1 when converted to unsigned int is 0xffffff*" -- or `0xffff`, or `0xffffffffffffffff`, or some other number. But always a big number.

Answer (score 3):

The point is the type of value `sizeof` returns.

> It's a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type, so converting `-1` to that type for the comparison produces the maximal value of the type, which is far larger than 5.

Comment: When I printed out the value of TOTAL_ELEMENTS I got 7

Comment: @Levon But there's a `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(d=-1;d <= ((int)TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
```

Comment: I think your answer is better ;) The code is probably taken from an exam/test question with a conscious "defect". Both yours and mine suggestions are correct but this one says "you can't catch me".

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is more clear:

```
for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++)
   printf("%d\n",array[d]);
```

And `size_t` case should not be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A more standard way to write this loop which works would be

```
for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++)
   ...
```

as was pointed out by correctly by several others here already, the problem lies with signed/unsigned values being compared. This construct would have avoided the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem works, when I do the following:

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS 7
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
  int d;

  for(d=-1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++)
      printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

  return 0;
}
```

This has something to do with comparing a negative number d=-1 with (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2). I believe it might be sizeof, butI will leave finding out why as an exercise.

Leaving your original #define as it was --

`#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))`

-- but using zero-based indexing also worked.

I'm not sure why your original TOTAL_ELEMENTS definition caused the loop not to print.