# Why is this for loop iteration not printing anything vs the other?

Tags: c++, string

2 Loops - just a simple string reversal.

However, I have an issue when I use two different end states. I just wanna' know why it's not printing anything.

```
for (unsigned int i = a.length() - 1; i != -1; i--)
    {
        b += a[i];
    }
    cout << a << "\n" << b << endl;
```

vs

```
for (unsigned int i = a.length() - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        b += a[i];
    }
    cout << a << "\n" << b << endl;
```

The second will not print anything - looking for an explanation why.

Sorry for the noob question, but certainly curious. Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one will also not print anything. Think about what "unsigned" means.

Comment: Well, this first loop actually does print something. Just not sure why the second one isn't...

For example: output for : "schamma doo"

schammma doo
ood ammmahcs
Press any key to continue . .

Oh! I simply changed it to a normally declared int and it worked.

Thank you!

Comment: The first loop tests i for unequality with a very big number.  The second tests, if i is greater than the biggest possible number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsigned and signed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/unsigned-and-signed-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

With an unsigned integral value `unsigned int i`, a condition like `i > -1` can never become true, whereas a condition `i != -1` can become true. The reason is that integral literal `-1`, when promoted to an unsigned value, is actually the same as `MAX_UNSIGNED`. And it is then easy to see that a value of type `unsigned int` can never be greater than `MAX_UNSIGNED`, whereas it can happen that it is `!= MAX_UNSIGNED`.

Try the following code:

```
unsigned int ui = -1;
printf("ui:%u ; MAX_UNSINGED: %u\n", ui, UINT_MAX);

bool onegreaterMinusOne = (1 > ui);
printf("1 > -1 in unsigned realm? %s\n", (onegreaterMinusOne ? "True" : "False"));

unsigned int anotherUI = 0;
printf("0 != -1 in unsigned realm? %s\n", (anotherUI != ui) ? "True" : "False");

anotherUI--;
printf("--anotherUI != -1 in unsigned realm? %s\n", (anotherUI != ui) ? "True" : "False");
```

Output:

```
ui:4294967295 ; MAX_UNSINGED: 4294967295
1 > -1 in unsigned realm? False
0 != -1 in unsigned realm? True
--anotherUI != -1 in unsigned realm? False
```

A little bit subtle is the last thing, where `unsigned int anotherUI=0; anotherUI--;` is evaluated (this corresponds to the last step in your first loop), because one might ask if "an unsigned underflow is defined behaviour". The answer is yes, as taken from the C++-standard (and copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221449/2630032)
):

> [...] A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>   because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned
>   integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the
>   largest value that can be represented by the resulting type. (ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999 (E) §6.2.5/9)

So `(unsigned)0 - (unsigned)1` equals `-1 modulo UINT_MAX+1`, or in other words, `UINT_MAX`.